# What's the best/clearest solution to adapt "two" versions of a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a fork of the redmine_backlogs plugin on github (https://github.com/SeyZ/redmine_backlogs).

I want to add some new **generic** features to improve the plugin. However, I need some **specific** changes for my company.

What's the best/clearest solution to adapt "two" versions of the plugin (the first version for everybody and the second one for my company) ?

When I add a feature in the generic_version of the backlogs, I want the same feature in my company_version. Not the contrary !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork the plugin with github for the generic/public version.
And make a fork/clone of that one for your company.

You can add public features and use `git pull` to get these features into your company version.
When adding company related features, the public version will not have these (unless you perform a `git push` I suppose, so better not do that!)

I *think* that you could also create an empty git repository of your company and use `git pull <url>` to get the public features into this version. In this situation you cannot easily/accidentally push your companies changes into the public version.